# Fetch all the values from a table in Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a Blog as my college project. Now i have a table named `blogs` and there are **5** attributes in the table.

```
blog_name, blog_user, blog_id, blog_date & blog_text
```

Now there are saveral entries in the blog.
I need a way to fetch the whole table and show the list of blog on a single page.
That is need a way to select the whole table and print the blog names using a while loop.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of those given answers then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
<% Blog.all.each do |blog| %>
  # code
<% end %>
```

I'd also advice you learning some Ruby/Rails basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

In your Controller

```
def index

@blog = Blog.all

end
```

In your view(index.html.erb)

```
<table border=1>

    <tr>
    <th>Blog Name</th>
    <th>Blog User</th>
    <th>Blog ID</th>
    <th>Blog Date</th>
    <th>Blog Text</th>
    </tr>

    <% @blog.each do |b| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= b.blog_name %></td>
    <td><%= b.blog_user %></td>
    <td><%= b.blog_id   %></td>
    <td><%= b.blog_date %></td>
    <td><%= b.blog_text %></td>
  </tr>  
    <% end %>
</table>
```

So,for every blog entry you will be getting all the details populated in a table view.